# python : arg_parser argument add alias

Tags: python, alias, argparse

I'm trying to have some specific printing with python argument parsing, but there is something i don't manage to do.

```
parser.add_argument('-m' , help="test a specific module")
```

Above is my code.

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -m M         test a specific module
```

Above is the result.

But what i want to have is :

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -m MODULE    test a specific module
```

I know it's not really important but i would really like to have this output.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be solved by adding `metavar`

```
parser.add_argument('-m', metavar='MODULE', help="test a specific module")
```

Comment: Working perfectly !